# Components navigate route

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-components, angular-component-router

How to naviage to another component from current component? I have tried like this:

account component:

```
vm.$onInit = function () {
    var jwt = accountService.getJWT();

    if (!jwt || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(jwt)) {
        this.$router.navigate(['registration']);
    }
};
```

This doesn't work for me :(

```
Component "Root" has no route config.
```

I have set $routerRootComponent

```
.value('$routerRootComponent', 'app')
.component('app', {
    template: '<ng-outlet></ng-outlet>',
    $routeConfig: [
        {path: '/registration', component: 'registration', useAsDefault: true},
        {path: '/registration/:referrer', component: 'registration'},

        {path: '/account', component: 'account'}
    ]
})
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tvarryG8ykZTGyfXK2cl?p=preview)

Comment: More information would be helpful. What and where is "another component" and what and where is "current component". How is this related to Angularjs? Looks like an Angular2 question.

Comment: I'm trying to change current location (account component) to another component (for example registration component).

Comment: Thats the same "info" your question contains and doesn't provide additional information. For routing it relevant if where routes are added (root component, child component, component with or without `<router-outlet>`) and where the component is (again root component, child component, ...) that contains the `this.$router.navigate(...)` code. Without this information there is not much one can suggest. It might be necessary to create a Plunker that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry... it's my one of the first experience to make questions here. http://plnkr.co/edit/tvarryG8ykZTGyfXK2cl?p=preview is plnkr with reproduction my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes (in the old router) need a name and `router.navigate()` expects the name to be used, otherwise you would need to use for example `router.navigateByUrl()`.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRAbmuE8bjgJ3Zwe5ISf?p=preview)